# IOS not playing urls from google cloud storage

Tags: ios, video, media-player, google-cloud-storage, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am storing my MP4 videos in google cloud storage and trying to play them in iOS device using MPMoviePlayerController but it is not playing. However if I upload same file on dropbox to public, it plays fine.

```
    let videoURLWithPath = "https://storage.googleapis.com/pioctave/577265bce6058511008a39dd/57bc34d5683eb51100173a46-video/pioctave.mp4"
    print(videoURLWithPath)
    let videoURL = NSURL(string: videoURLWithPath)


    moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.header_video_img!.frame.size.height)

    self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.fullscreen = false
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = true

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Fullscreen
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFill

    moviePlayer.play()
```

I used the same file from GCS in android, it worked fine. Following is the sample public url to the video.

https://storage.googleapis.com/pioctave/577265bce6058511008a39dd/57bc34d5683eb51100173a46-video/pioctave.mp4

Is there any header issue or is there some issue in device side. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated. Use AVPlayerViewController instead of MPMoviePlayerController.

Here is the code:

```
let videoURL = NSURL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/pioctave/577265bce6058511008a39dd/57bc34d5683eb51100173a46-video/pioctave.mp4")
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
    playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

Comment: this starts the first 5 sec video and never proceeds ahead of that, can you please help with that?

Comment: Add observer to player item:

playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferEmpty", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackLikelyToKeepUp", options: .New, context: nil)
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "playbackBufferFull", options: .New, context: nil)

Comment: then Implement below method:
override public func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    if object is AVPlayerItem {
        switch keyPath {
            case "playbackBufferEmpty":
               // player.play() 
            case "playbackLikelyToKeepUp":
                // Hide loader
               // player.pause()
            case "playbackBufferFull":
                // Hide loader
                              // player.pause()

        }
    }
}